How does the angle of the objective vector determine whether a linear program has a maximum or minimum?
I'm working on a 2D linear optimization problem with the following constraints:
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1 + x_2 \ge -1, \\
x_1 - x_2 \le 3, \\
x_2 \ge -1,
\end{cases}
$$
and the objective function
$$
z = c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2,
$$
where the vector is $\mathbf{c} = (c_1, c_2)$.
I’m supposed to determine for which values of the angle $\theta$ (measured from the $x_1$-axis to $\mathbf{c}$) the problem admits a finite maximum or a finite minimum (or both).
Here’s what I’ve reasoned so far:

The feasible region is unbounded above in $x_2$.
If $c_2 > 0$, it seems that the maximum is unbounded (because you can go to large positive $x_2$) but a minimum might exist.
If $c_2 < 0$, it seems that the minimum is unbounded (because you can again go to large positive $x_2$, making $c_2 x_2$ very negative) but a maximum might exist.
If $c_2 = 0$, then $z = c_1 x_1$, which suggests I should also look at whether $x_1$ is effectively bounded in the feasible region.

My confusion is how exactly to formalize this in terms of the angle $\theta$.
My questions:

How do I precisely show that $c_2 > 0$ makes the maximum unbounded but guarantees a finite minimum, and vice versa for $c_2 < 0$?
Are there standard methods or theorems that clearly link the direction (angle) of the objective vector to the boundedness of the optimal solution in this kind of wedge-shaped feasible region?

I’d greatly appreciate any insights or references that clarify how to rigorously argue about the existence of maxima/minima based on the orientation of $\mathbf{c}$. Thank you!

Let us first draw the feasible region.

Let's now add an objective function, say $c = (0, -\frac{1}{2})$, illustrated by the green arrow. The green line at the base of $c$ is a visual aid that divides $\mathbb{R}^2$ into two half-spaces. The blue and orange arrows are feasible vectors, ie. they sit in the feasible region. However, the blue vectors have positive objective value while the orange vectors have negative objective values. Clearly any feasible blue vector will have bounded length so the linear program is bounded above.

Let us now rotate the objective so that the green line is parallel to the left boundary. Again the blue vectors are feasible with positive objective value. We can try to increase the objective value by considering "longer" feasible vectors but as the angle with $c$ approaches 90 the objective value goes to zero. In this case too the LP is bounded above.

Finally, let's rotate the objective a hair more. I've drawn one feasible vector $x_0$ with positive objective value. Let $z_0 = c^\top x_0 > 0$. Notice we can make $x_0$ as long as we want while maintaining feasibility.

In other words, $tx_0$ is feasible for all $t \geq 0$ and thus our objective is unbounded.
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} c^\top (tx_0) = \lim_{t \to \infty} t c^\top x_0 = \lim_{t \to \infty} t z_0 = \infty$$
